# JHipster : implement AutoComplete by replacing ComboBox with a NgbTypeahead with observable

Tags: angular, jhipster, ng-bootstrap

I want to replace the combobox, used in **JHipster**(6.8.0) with an "Autocomplete" field, I found on [Antonio Goncalves's](https://antoniogoncalves.org/2018/11/08/jhipster-angular-primeng-and-autocomplete/) blog the way to do it with PrimeNG, but I did not want to add an another new library of Widgets.

I realized that JHipster was already using the "Bootstrap widgets" library (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) for entering dates with "ngb-datepicker".

This library provides a component allowing an "Autocomplete" feature with **"Ngb-typeahead"** directive.
I am not an Angular specialist, so it was not easy for me to find the best way to do it. That said, the changes to be made are relatively small, and the most important : **it's works**.

There are the chnages:

**JDL file** used to generate JHipster sample application

```
entity Contact {
    firstName String required,
    lastName String required,
    email String
}

entity Language {
    alpha3b String required maxlength(3),
    alpha2 String required maxlength(2)
    name String required,
    flag32  String,
    flag128 String,
    activated Boolean
}

relationship ManyToOne {
    Contact{language(name) required} to Language
}

filter *

service all with serviceClass
paginate Contact with pagination
dto * with mapstruct
```

**contact-update.component.html**

replace existing  control with  :

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="jhcontact2App.contact.language" for="field_language">Language</label>
<!--                     <select class="form-control" id="field_language" name="language" formControlName="languageId"> -->
<!--                         <option *ngIf="!editForm.get('languageId')!.value" [ngValue]="null" selected></option> -->
<!--                         <option [ngValue]="languageOption.id" *ngFor="let languageOption of languages; trackBy: trackById">{{ languageOption.name }}</option> -->
<!--                     </select> -->

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field_language" formControlName="language"
                           placeholder="{{ 'jhcontact2App.contact.language.placeholder' | translate }}"                         
                           (selectItem)="selectedItem($event)"
                           [ngbTypeahead]="search"
                           [inputFormatter]="formatter"
                           [resultFormatter]="formatter"
                           [editable]='false' />

                </div>
                <div *ngIf="editForm.get('language')!.invalid && (editForm.get('language')!.dirty || editForm.get('language')!.touched)">
                    <small class="form-text text-danger"
                           *ngIf="editForm.get('language')?.errors?.required" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.required">
                        This field is required.
                    </small>
                </div>
```

**contact-update.component.ts**

Update ngOnInit, updateFrom, createForm methods

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ contact }) => {
      this.updateForm(contact);
// remove service call to populate Languages Collection
//      this.languageService.query()
//               .subscribe((res: HttpResponse<ILanguage[]>) => (this.languages = res.body || []));
    });
  }
```

```js
  updateForm(contact: IContact): void {
    this.editForm.patchValue({
      id: contact.id,
      firstName: contact.firstName,
      lastName: contact.lastName,
      email: contact.email,
// Patch full Language object instead id      
//      languageId: contact.languageId,
      language: {id: contact.languageId, name: contact.languageName}
    });
  }
```

```js
  private createFromForm(): IContact {
    // get full object from form
    const language: ILanguage = this.editForm.get(['language'])!.value;
    return {
      ...new Contact(),
      id: this.editForm.get(['id'])!.value,
      firstName: this.editForm.get(['firstName'])!.value,
      lastName: this.editForm.get(['lastName'])!.value,
      email: this.editForm.get(['email'])!.value,      
//      languageId: this.editForm.get(['languageId'])!.value     
      languageId: language.id
    };
  }
```

Add new functions used by Ngb-typeahead:

```js
  // Add formatter
  formatter = (x: { name: string }) => x.name;

  // the seach function
  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
        text$.pipe(
            debounceTime(300),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            switchMap(term => this.languageService.searchByName( term ))
        )
  // the OnSelect 
  selectedItem(language: ILanguage): void {
      this.editForm.patchValue({
      language: language.name
    });
  }
```

**language.service.ts**

```js
  searchByName(term: string): any {
    if (term === '') {
      return of([]);
    }
    const options = createRequestOption({ 'name.contains': term });
    return this.http.get<ILanguage[]>(this.resourceUrl, { params: options });
  }
```

This last point does not entirely satisfy me because I would like to reuse the "initial query generated method" of the **language.service.ts** component, but this method uses RXJS and returns an "Observable" and **I don't know how to wait for the http request ends to pass the result to the function**.

**initial query generated method**

```js
  query(req?: any): Observable<EntityArrayResponseType> {
    const options = createRequestOption(req);
    return this.http.get<ILanguage[]>(this.resourceUrl, { params: options, observe: 'response' });
  }
```

If anyone can help me with this?

Comment: http.get() returns an Observable, the fact  that you typed searchByName() as "any" does not change this (read https://angular.io/guide/http). I see no real difference between searchByName() and query(), in both cases an Observable is returned and you must call subscribe() on it to process data returned by server.

Comment: Thanks for your interest Gael, my analysis is wrong.

Comment: in the searchByName() case the method return an observable of ILanguage, but in the case of Query() the methode return an Observable of HttpResponse that I cant be used as an iterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to reuse the JHispter generated "query()" method!

Like this :

```js
  // the search function
  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(term => term.length < 2 ? [] : this.languageService.query({ 'name.contains': term })),
      map((res: HttpResponse<ILanguage[]>) => (res.body || []))
    );
```

**searchByName()** method not needed anymore.